# Add Start up animation on Pie chart using angular-nvd3 chart library

Tags: angularjs, animation, pie-chart, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I need to add Start up animation on Pie chart  in angular-nvd3 chart library , it is possible to add animation to some parts but I could not set animation for pie chart .

```
here is sample code http://plnkr.co/edit/vtKWU0?p=preview
```

Comment: Posting some code might help others respond to your question

Comment: Did you ever get this implemented? I'd like to do the same thing.